# Unable to parse date with time zone

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, jakarta-ee

For the observation, I just added the fragment of my code. It work well for format date with time zone offset but unable to parse what was formatted.

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SZ");
    Date javaDate = new Date();
    String stringDate = format.format(javaDate);
    System.out.println("Date: " + stringDate);

    try {
        javaDate = format.parse(stringDate); //reverse of format
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any straight forward way? Consider that `20140916130644.236+0600` is your date string you should parse it with time zone what will be your date format? You may easily parse `yyyyMMddHHmmss.S` pattern while `.` is not a fact, main fact is `Z` while parsing not for formatting.

Comment: show the original date format like 2014-14-02 02:14:15

Comment: use '.' instead of `.` in `"yyyyMMddHHmmss.SZ"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward way is the date parse format should be look like `yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZ`, Formatting format and parsing format may be different. Formatting format (`yyyyMMddHHmmss.SZ`) should not be use for parsing. Parsing format(`yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZ`) may be use for formatting. To avoid unexpected result/exception better to use `yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZ` format for formatting/parsing rather then `yyyyMMddHHmmss.SZ`

Answer (score 3):

Because `.` is not valid, remove it and try like this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSZ");
```

or if you want to have '.' then use like this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.'SZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SZ");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.'SZ");
```

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings.
>   Within date and time pattern strings, **unquoted** letters from 'A' to 'Z'
>   and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing
>   the components of a date or time string. Text can be **quoted** using
>   single quotes (') to avoid interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

`'T'` and `'Z'` are considered here as constants. You need to pass Z without the quotes. Moreover you need to specify the timezone in the input string.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```